# Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function (Code reuse scenario)

Tags: javascript, function

I am trying to reuse a huge function as follows

```
var hugeFunction = function(bell, whistle, another, param, another, param) {
    //lots of work
}
```

and right below it, in the same function, we have

```
self.useFunctionInstance = hugeFunction(bell, whistle, another, param, another, param);
```

So when I call

```
self.useFunctionInstance()
```

I get the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function on line 3862 (helloApp#undefined)
```

I tried everything, and read alot, but I don't get it still!! Any help please!?

Edit: The huge function is essentially a browse function with tons of parameters, and doesn't return anything, I just want to be able to call it, but if I have to make it return something, then it's fine, I'll just do that. Is there a way to have a function use another function? I might be asking the question in a wrong way, thanks alot for your help guys!!

Comment: Are you trying to make `useFunctionInstance` also to invoke `hugeFunction`?

Comment: Try without passing parameters. Like self.useFunctionInstance = hugeFunction;

Comment: Yeah, i am trying to invoke hugFunction, because I need to use it, however I was trying to reuse its code, by having another function call it

Comment: @xp500 Yeah that will invoke the function, except i need to call the parameters!

Comment: @Tralala I don't understand if you want self.useFunctionInstance to be a function or to be what hugeFunction() returns.

Comment: @xp500 Thanks alot, it's to be a function, I am trying the answers right now!! Thanks for the help, I am starting to understand it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to assign a function to `useFunctionInstance` if you want to invoke it from that property.

```
// Assign anonymous function that invokes `hugeFunction()`
self.useFunctionInstance = function() {
    return hugeFunction(bell, whistle, another, param, another, param);
};
```

---

The way you had it, you were invoking immediately, and assigning its return value, which was apparently `undefined`.

---

If you need to capture the current state of the variables permanently, then you can use `.bind()` to create a new function with those values bound.

```
self.useFunctionInstance = hugeFunction.bind(null, bell, whistle, another, param, another, param);
```

Comment: Did you mean `self` instead of `null`?

Comment: @thefourtheye: In this case, it seems that the original function isn't associated with a particular object, so I'm assuming `this` isn't used. But you're right, it should be `self` if that's the expectation.

Comment: Hi this  hugeFunction.bind(null, bell, whistle, another, param, another, param); seems to be what i want, but it seems to be binding the current state of all the scope or something, can we pass it parameters instead, I am not sure how to use it, thanks alot!

Comment: @Tralala: Right. it binds the current state of the variables. If that's not what you want, use the first solution. It'll use the state of the variables at the time of invocation.

Comment: Thanks so much! I spent like all night trying to figure it out, coding at night is not good I guess, until you guys show up :)

Answer (score 0):

You assigned return value of hugeFunction to useFunctionInstance and it seems you didn't return anything.

You should return closure to do what you want.

```
var hugeFunction = function(bell, whistle, another, param, another, param) {
  return function() {
    //lots of work
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it like this:

```
self.useFunctionInstance = hugeFunction;
```

And then call it like:

```
self.useFunctionInstance(bell, whistle, another, param, another, param);
```

The problem was you were assigning the function return value (as well as calling it) to `self.useFunctionInstance`.

Comment: If you don't mind using the parameters for `self.useFunctionInstance` then you're good to go with what I gave you.

Comment: Yeah, that's definitely good, in that case, I wish I could upvote it, I am still new here! It won't let me, I am trying to get away without having to call the parameters in the self.useFunctionInstance() call, but have it pass it to the parent function. As in the type of inheritance that specifies the case of the parent